# Questions on sadhana specifics and responsibility of responders

Tags: discussion

This is not really a question but I do not know where else to post. Off and on we see questions regarding yoga , meditation and chakra practices. Some of these are very personal and specific to the meditation practice of the user. Anyone who is responding to questions on individual practices should be extremely circumspect in how they word their responses as well as the amount and nature of information they share. It is highly irresponsible to just refer to a yoga text and copy/paste it without knowing the specifics of the practices of the user and without having attained a certain level of yoga sadhana ourselves that qualifies us to teach and guide. Chakra meditations specifically, if not done right can have adverse effects. And whosever advice the user has followed will reap the karma of guiding them incorrectly. More importantly, the person would be responsible for derailing the sadhana of the user. Unless one has the yogic energy levels to guide and teach and energy-correct from a distance, one must not respond to such personal advice questions with generic guidelines from books. Thank you. I am writing this in the interest of both the questioners and responders.

Add-on: If the community is not sure who has the necessary attainment to answer such Q's we should just start closing them as personal advice. Better to refrain from answering than be responsible for incorrect practices.

Mods: Can you make this a sticky please.

Comment: Answerer can make disclaimer or we (community) can have disclaimer in side bar as discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104821/260388)

Comment: @Pandya the problem is that answerers don't make these disclaimers. regardless, that is not enough show of responsibility. only learned teachers may provide guidance to such questions.

Comment: @Pandya Besides disclaimers may protect from legal responsibility but not from karmic and moral responsibility.

Comment: I agree. Questions asking for advanced chakra meditation practices should be treated like personal advice questions and closed. These are like prescribing a medicine to a patient. A patient should go to a doctor only not an internet forum. Similarly, a practitioner who is following advanced techniques should go to a guru only.

Comment: Yeah we should close such questions because a) such techniques have to be practiced under the guidance of a guru only and b) if someone here does know the details, they still shouldn't answer because again, it has be practiced under the guidance of guru so regardless of someone knowing the answer or not, chakras involve powerful energies and a guru is required to keep a check over it otherwise it can render a person insane if they try such techniques without apt preparation.